# AngularJS - how to create deferred object from image object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred

I'm trying to create a deferred object from simple image object creation like below:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'some url';
image.onload = function() {
   // some code
}
```

now... how to create a deferred object using $q library within AngularJS? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that there is some factory, where you are planning to put this function. Then:

```
.factory('utils', function($q) {
    return {
        createImage: function(src) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                image = new Image();
            image.onload = function() {
                deferred.resolve(image);
            };
            image.src = src;
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Then you would use it as usual:

```
utils.createImage('/assets/images/big-logo.png').then(function(imgObj) {
    console.log(imgObj);
});
```

**Angular 1.3**. Since Angular 1.3 version promise service `$q` also allows new syntax similar to native [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) constructor. Then above function can be rewritten:

```
createImage: function(src) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            resolve(image);
        };
        image.src = src;
    });
}
```

You can use both version with 1.3.

And finally simple **demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/MbQEDPHoAurFd6JwHTji?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for valuable point. I'm so used to Kris Kowal's version that completely missed this important update to native syntax!

Comment: I know what you mean ;) Used Kowal's version for years, and was quite suprised when seeing the new syntax the first time.